# Accessing values from inner array

Tags: php

```
Array ( [err] => [num] => 1 [result] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 85 [proj_id] => 85 [1] => Automatic Mobile Alert System For Lethal Gas Detection [proj_item_title] => Automatic Mobile Alert System For Lethal Gas Detection [2] => GSM PROJECTS [proj_category] => GSM PROJECTS [3] => 5000 [actual_price] => 5000 [4] => 4000 [discount_price] => 4000 [5] => 5 [rating] => 5 [6] => automatic-mobile-alert-system-for-lethal-gas-detection [friendly_url] => automatic-mobile-alert-system-for-lethal-gas-detection [7] => gsnrtmccfoqqkgb8qs2ni5hud36c032j [session_id] => gsnrtmccfoqqkgb8qs2ni5hud36c032j [8] => 85 [9] => 2017-01-20 [date_added] => 2017-01-20 [10] => 1 [qty] => 1 ) ) )
```

I need to access elements from the array "result". How can I access them. Please help me.

Comment: $data["result"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo $array['result'][0][0]`

Will return `85`

`$result = $array['result'][0]`

Will give you a nice way to save the Result array into another Array.

So you can do

`$result[0] //Returns 85 again`

Answer (score 0):

Your `$data['result']` is an array so you can simply loop over the elements

```
foreach($data['result'] as $result) {
   var_dump($result);
   echo $result[0]; 
   echo $result['proj_item_title'];
   echo $result['proj_id']; //etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you Robert, Moe and Siddiqui for the help. I am grateful for the time you spent on my question. Time is precious.